# CGO core dump analysis using GDB

Tags: go, gdb, cgo

The following GO code is using CGO to call C function test3(), which calls test2(), which calls test1(). The program will crash, because there is a NULL pointer assignment in test1(). When I use GDB, I am not getting the CGO stack trace. I need help to get the stack trace for CGO part.

```
package main

/*
void test1(void) {
   int *p = (int*)NULL;
   *p = 30;
}


void test2(void) { 
    test1();
}

void test3(void) { 
    test2();
}
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.test3();
}
```

```
(gdb) bt

#0  runtime.raise () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:150

#1  0x000000000043793b in runtime.dieFromSignal (sig=6) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:428

#2  0x0000000000437d9d in runtime.sigfwdgo (sig=6, info=0xc0000094b0, ctx=0xc000009380,

    ~r3=<optimized out>) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:631

#3  0x0000000000437020 in runtime.sigtrampgo (sig=<optimized out>, info=0xc0000094b0, ctx=0xc000009380)

    at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:289

#4  0x000000000044ed43 in runtime.sigtramp () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:357

#5  <signal handler called>

#6  runtime.raise () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:150

#7  0x000000000043793b in runtime.dieFromSignal (sig=6) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:428

#8  0x0000000000437ada in runtime.crash () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:520

#9  0x0000000000449dd1 in runtime.fatalthrow.func1 () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:833

#10 0x0000000000425c97 in runtime.fatalthrow () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:826

#11 0x0000000000425ac2 in runtime.throw (s=...) at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774

#12 0x00000000004378ec in runtime.sigpanic () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:378

#13 0x0000000000456730 in main.main ()
```

I tried GDB to get the stack trace from the core dump. But not getting stack trace for CGO part.

Comment: My GDB version is 

gdb --version

GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1

go version go1.19.4 linux/amd64